# Kubernetes set service annotation value dynamically

Tags: kubernetes

My goal is to have a Kubernetes Service with dynamic annotation value, is it possible to bind ConfigMap object within Kubernetes Service annotation. Tried googling the question unfortunately
without success. My experience to use ConfigMap only in conjunction with Deployment. My guess it's not possible but wanted to have a confirmation. Probably someone knows a way to have it.
I always is able to create my Kubernetes Service using direct kubectl command without providing yaml file and set the annotation value from system env values for example, I'm curious if there more elegant way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe why you want it to be dynamic? What's the source of this dynamic value? how often do you want to update it? `kubectl` is just an API client for [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#service-v1-core) so all you need is a http client to [patch a service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#patch-service-v1-core)

Comment: Let say I have a script which runs over all yaml file and deploy them on Kubernetes, I have https service with has 


 annotations:
   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: <arn: ..... >,
<arn: ..... > value should be provided dynamically

this value is different fro DEV and PROD env.

Comment: Ok, sounds like you are entering the world of templated deploys. [helm](https://helm.sh/) is usually used for move complex deploys requiring variable substitution (like for multiple environments). You can inject variables from values files or on the command line and `{{ .Values.certarn }}` in the yaml

Comment: I have similar issue but we don't use helm. We use deployment yaml's and customizations. Any idea it can be done with customizations?

Actually I need is pass region name as dynamic and it will form resource arn cert from it.

Comment: Take a look at Kubernetes Ambassador tool, probably you will find it helpful,
At the moment our project is paused for a while, but I think later will try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [helm](https://helm.sh/).

This requires setting up a helm ["chart"](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/) for your deploy which includes a set of yaml templates.

```
helm create my-app
```

An example service template with a variable annotation `./my-app/templates/service.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app-service
  name: my-app-service
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: {{ .Values.service.certarn }}
spec:
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8091
  selector:
    app: my-app-instance
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Then the "value" can be set at deploy time:

```
helm install ./my-app -v certarn=12345:12345:123454513433
```

Normally you end up with lots of values with a more complex structure so you end up with dev/test/prod values file:

```
helm install ./my-app -f values.dev.yaml
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, it sounds exactly what I need. but seems a bit overkilling to get using helm, the tool I'm not familiar with it yet, assume in future will have to learn it. but for now, wanted something simple

Comment: @DenisVoloshin, can you please share how you were able to do it? I am in the same boat

Comment: @mark try [kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) it can also modify the static release before deployment